# Enforce unique values across list row

Tags: enforce-uniquevalue

I have a list where we track an employees performance by awarding badges. I have 1 column for employee name and 4 choice columns, each including the 4 available badges. How can I prevent the same badge from being selected twice for the employee?  I tried selecting 'enforce unique values' in my 4 badge columns but that restricts the same selection from other employees, whereas I want to restrict the value across the row. For example, Mary Smith can only earn the "accountable" badge once and the other 3 badges must be unique but John Jones can earn the "accountable" badge.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using four Yes/No checkboxes?, each one named for a different badge.

From your question it does not appear there is any other data attached to the drop-down boxes, such as the date the badge was earned.  Wouldn't a simple Boolean accomplish your goal?

The only issue I see with using the basic check-boxes would be if the order the badges were awarded mattered.  That was not specified in your question, but let's say it was.

In that situation you would just tie a date selector to each of the checkboxes.  For example, one field would be Yes/No for "Accountable Badge", and the next would be "Accountable Date".  In PowerQuery or other reporting tools, you would be able to generate a report detailing the date order the badges were awarded.

To make it even simpler, you could just forget the Yes/No fields and make all four badge fields as Dates.  Therefore a `null` date means the badge hasn't been awarded.

If there is some other facet of the question I am missing, please let me know.

Comment: The order in which the badge is awarded does not matter.  I did try to change the checkbox to a date field and adjusted the Picture/Hyperlink field JSON as follows but it did not display the image: {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "60px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=if([$Accountable Badge] > 'null', 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/HR/SiteAssets/ACCOUNTABLE3.png',  '')"

  }
}

Comment: Try this instead... remove the single quotation marks from null; its not a string, but a value; also you cannot use > for the comparison, use != for does not equal

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column that concatenates the values of the four badge fields:

- Go to List Settings -> Create Column. Name the column and set the type to "Calculated".
- In the formula box, if your badge columns are named Badge1, Badge2, Badge3, and Badge4:

`=[Badge1]&[Badge2]&[Badge3]&[Badge4]`

- Enforce uniqueness on this new calculated column. This will prevent the same combination of badges from being selected twice for the same employee.

Try this and let me know if it helps.